# How to get the poolsize per eVault tasks by API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to get the poolsize per eVault tasks by the API.
I have found that API value is different from the Portal value.

Please tell me how to get the same value as the Portal.

Display of python API:

```
import SoftLayer
client = SoftLayer.Client()
evault = client['Account'].getEvaultNetworkStorage(mask='mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[tasks]')
print( evault[0]['tasks'][0] )
{'usedPoolsize': -1418239875, 'id': 373, 'name': 'Linux_Backup'}
```

Display of SoftLayerCustomerPortal (Storage-Backup):

```
Task ID　Name　Pool Size
373　Linux_Backup　22.7GB
```

Answer (score 0):

The values displayed from `API` are in bytes([SoftLayer_Container_Network_Storage_Evault_Vault_Task](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Network_Storage_Evault_Vault_Task)).

Please change these values from bytes to gigabytes.

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)
[SoftLayer_Container_Network_Storage_Evault_Vault_Task](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Network_Storage_Evault_Vault_Task)

Comment: Thank you for answer.

Please tell me how to change the value, From the API value '-1418239875' to the Portal value '22.7GB'.

Comment: After reviewing some test accounts, I was not able to get pool sizes with negative values. Please open a SoftLayer ticket in order to isolate the problem and give you better information. I recommend you to provide all details about this Evault (i.e. ids). Because this is a sensitive information I cannot ask you about more details of your problem here.